# How i can i cancel the subscritpion for my subscribers

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am having problem with my sandbox i don't know how to cancel the subscription for my subscribers in sandbox paypal.

Is it also possible to delete the subscription in sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

To cancel your customer's recurring payment profile:

1.Log in to your PayPal account.
2.Click Profile near the top of the page.
3.Click My selling tools.
4.Click Update beside "My automatic payments."
5.Click "Active" under Overview to display all active payments.
6.Tick the checkbox beside the name(s) of the customer(s) whose profile(s) you want to cancel.
7.Click Cancel beside "Actions."

Comment: Hi PP_MTS_Chad, I only use the sandboxpaypal not the live one...I went to the https://www.sandbox.paypal.com. i log-in as the busissness account,i click the profil on top,after that i could not see the My selling tools.

Comment: There is no my selling tools,..if you said paypal.com i haven't tried to register there,I registered at paypal.developer.com

Comment: Hi, what happens after i cancelled the subscrition for my subscribers,can i refund their payments ?

Comment: Yes, you can refund transactions even after the subscription has been cancelled.

Comment: How to refund the amount ?

Comment: HI PP_MT_Chad, if we created accounts in developer.paypal.com,our account also created in paypal.com which is the live one ?please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: accounts created from within your developer.paypal.com developer account do not create live accounts.